# Div selected - Unread Message - read messsage like facebook inbox

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, cookies

I´m trying to make Left Nav link like facebook inbox.
There´re 3 differences kinds of div 1. unread(light blue)  2.read(white)  3. selected(dark blue)

Actually it´s very easy if I do it in the normal way. Which mean I need to reload the page everytime I click to read each message.

But this case, I want to do it in ajax way completely. I have done all the job. But get the problem in last step.

**The idea is :** I use cookie (jquery.cookie plugin) to store the **last clicked Div Id** Then When I click on the div each time to read the message, The **last clicked div id** Must turn to be white.
(Because the message has been read).

When I click on unread message Div. There´s a problem:
**the unread-message Div turn to be the light blue again**

I use lots of method both normal javascript and jQuery.

Well let ´s see my div first:
**Example div:**
:::the id of div is array from database but here I make it easy to see.

```
<div id ='001' class='normal' onclick=readmsg(id_msg1)></div>
<div id ='002' class='normal' onclick=readmsg(id_msg2)></div>
<div id ='003' class='normal' onclick=readmsg(id_msg3)></div>
```

**In Javascript**

```
function readmsg(id_msg) // or 2 or 3 & so on .....


 $.cookie('last_read', id_msg1);// set cookie at once



document.getElementById(id_msg1).className = "inbx_selected"; // div clicked just now--> selected:let´s say dark blue./// I have no problem with this.
```

This is all I have tried in order to change the class unread --> to class read.

```
var ck= $.cookie('last_read');  

    $("#"+id_msg).addClass('inbx_unread'); // 

    $("#"+last_read).removeClass('inbx_unread');// get the last ID of clicked div and remove class unread which´s light-blue
```

I have also tried the normal javascript like:

```
document.getElementById(last_read).className.replace("inbx_unread","");
```

// I have more code here But as I mentioned above that I finished with that. The only one problem is the unread(light-blue) turn back to light-blue again after I click on other div.

**I have checked in firebug and alert, I get correct value.**

I don´t know other ways to store temporaly data like cookie does.

TO be shorter question, How to stop the unread Div that has been clicked to turn back to its original class again after I click on another div ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a slightly different approach.
You could use just jQuery events.

the HTML

```
<div id ='001' class='message unread'>Message 1</div>
<div id ='002' class='message unread'>Message 2</div>
<div id ='003' class='message unread'>Message 3</div>
```

and the jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $(".message").click(function() {

        // we get the clicked element ID
        var id_msg = $(this).attr('id');

        // we read the cookie, to remove the previous selected class to the last_read element
        var last_read = $.cookie('last_read');
        $('#' + last_read).removeClass("inbx_selected");

        // we set the cookie, so we keep can remove the selected class in the next click
        $.cookie('last_read', id_msg);

        //
        // probably, here you should do some AJAX post to update the message status at the database
        // 

        // we remove the unread class, and add teh selected class
        $(this).removeClass("inbx_unread").addClass("inbx_selected");

    });

});
```

you can check a working jsfiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/QaMJZ/1/

hope it helps, good luck!

Comment: I think I would re-build my part. And try the code you gave me.
Thank you for you rhard work to just help me to find the solution.

Comment: you're right, the jsfiddel doesn't work in safari. but it works when you view the real html file in localhost. you can dowload this file and check it out: http://cl.ly/code/1M1f1c1g0Z0I